# jquery ui slider - changing the position of the handle

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, slider, jquery-ui-slider

I'm using a jquery ui slider with a play/pause button to control a d3.js animation. When i press the play button, i'd like the slider handle to move along, any way to do that?

Likewise, is there any way to position the slider at a specific step within the slider? I still want the max and min to remain the same but for example, if i want the handle to start at the last step when the page loads instead of the first one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `setInterval` and `stopInterval` see [there](http://www.pagecolumn.com/javascript/setinterval.htm)

Lets say you have play button that should invoke under mentioned method and switch to pause mode.

Some example where slider moves each sec and represent hours:

**play**

```
var hoursInterval = setInterval(function(){
        var timeOfDay = (localStorage['hour']==23)?0:parseInt(localStorage['hour'])+1;
        $("#playHour").slider("value",timeOfDay);
    },1000);
```

**pause**

```
....
clearInterval(hourInterval);
```

Suppose it will help you